# How to access virtual property from another object in my object

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a user model, and that user has a virtual country. The country has a name which I am trying to access. It just won't print out in my view, it's just blank.

My `User` model has this.

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
```

And the `Country` model has a `getName` for the country.
My index looks like this:

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter,string searchString, int? page)
{
    List<User> allUsers = _userManager.Users.ToList();
    return View(allUsers);
}
```

Now, when I try to show it on my Index page like this:

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="even pointer">
    <td class="a-center ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records">
    </td>
    <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
    <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
    <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.Name)</td>
    <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>
```

the firstname, lastname, email and city show up. But the `Country` name doesn't. How can that be?

Comment: can you paste please the body of your _userManager to show how you set the Users property? It might be a case of just adding the `dbcontext.Users.Include(x => x.Country)`

Comment: The answers below are assuming you are using Entity Framework. If you are please add the appropriate tag (Entity-Framework-6 or Entity-Framework-Core). Otherwise add some info about the ORM you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the County model is never getting loaded from the database before you do the .ToList() ... After that ToList call, then the objects are detached from the database and lazy loading wont work.

Try this:
_userManager.Users.Include("Country").ToList();

Also, just taking out the ToList() call would probably allow lazy loading to work but would be a performance issue if the user list becomes large.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: this worked! thanks! My list of users is very large. Around 9000 so wont try without ToList()

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem accessing virtual properties from the view. Make sure you are either calling `Country.getName()` or your `Name` property has a getter like

```cs
public string Name { get; }
```

Also by convention C# methods are Pascal Case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `Include(x => x.Country)` in the place where you set the `_userManager/Users` property, it should be just something like

```
dbcontext.Users.Include(x => x.Country)
```

Please notice that `Include` should be added before calling things like `ToList();`, to make sure the generated SQL query contains the needed logic.